# Returning a string that begins at the input parameter index of the String

Tags: java, for-loop, return, substring, string-length

The Method name is `getTheString()`

The Return type is `String`

And the Input parameters is `int`

I have to return a string that begins at input parameter index position of the String str which is the instance variable. Returns empty string if the input parameter index position is larger than or equal to the string length.

An example would be

If `str = “Hawaii”`

getTheString(8) returns “ “

getTheString(2) returns
“waii”

I don't know why nothing happens when I execute it or how to fix it could someone help.

```
public class LoopM
{
   public int a, b;
   public String str;
   
   public LoopM(){
    }
   
   public String getTheString(int f){
       
       str = "Hawaii";
       
       int length = str.length();
       
       for(f = length; f < 10; f++){
           
           return str.substring(f);
        }
       
       return str.substring(f);
    }
   
   public static void main(String args[]){
       //used for testing

       LoopM me = new LoopM();
       me.getTheString(2);
      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to this :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getTheString(2));
    }

    public static String getTheString(int f) {

        String str = "Hawaii";

        return (f > str.length() || f < 0) ? "" : str.substring(f);
    }

}
```

Output :

```
waii
```

Comment: @combovn Is this helpful ?

Comment: yes it is helpful but I don't understand why a ? operator in the return statement could you please explain

Comment: Yes it is helpful and forget about my last comment it took me a little to understand why the ? operator but yes it works and makes sense

Comment: @combovn It's called ternary operator.

Comment: @combovn Read about it.

Comment: @combovn if you have single condition, then you go for ternary operator.

Comment: @combovn It works like if condition is true, then statement before colon will executed otherwise, statement after colon will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using constructor to set value of `str` field instead of hardcoding it inside `getTheString` method, also the loop with the `return` statement inside is a bit strange.

Also you should check if the input parameters are valid (i.e., if `str` is not `null` and that `f` is not negative and less than `str.length()`

Thus, the code may be improved as follows:

```java
public class LoopM {
    public int a, b;
    public String str;

    public LoopM() {
        this("Hawaii");
    }

    public LoopM(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
   
   public String getTheString(int f) {
       
       int length = null == str? -1 : str.length();
       
       return f > -1 && f < length ? str.substring(f) : "";
    }
   
   public static void main(String args[]){
       //used for testing

       LoopM me = new LoopM();
       System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", me.getTheString(2));  // prints "waii"
       System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", me.getTheString(10));  // prints ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement consists of a ternary condition similar to if-else conditions. If the index is greater than the length of the string than it will return " " else it will return substring from the input index

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("String that begins at 2 index : "+getTheString(2)); // Output waii
        System.out.println("String that begins at 8 index : "+getTheString(8));// Output ""
    }

    public static String getTheString(int index) {

        String str = "Hawaii";

        return index > str.length() ? "" : str.substring(index);
    }

}
```

Comment: @combovn, did you get the logic of return statement?